# How to read object type of list into pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, list

type(output)

> list

print(output)

> Profile(username='0000_', name='ha', profile_photo='/pic/profile_images%2F712711040.jpg', tweets_count=159, following_count=89, followers_count=34, likes_count=118, is_verified=False, banner_photo='/pic/profile_banners%2F2582365986%', biography='glory', user_id=255986, location=' ', website=None),

json.dumps(output)

> TypeError: Object of type Profile is not JSON serializable

Comment: ```json.dumps``` only takes an ```str``` as an argument

Comment: in question you asked to convert object into dataframe while you are using json.dumps() but it will convert your `object`  into `string`.. see this for [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp) ..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([profile.__dict__])
```

with profile is your instance of class Profile